# How to apply CSS3 transitions through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, slide, css-transitions

I'm having some major headache trying to apply CSS3 transitions to a slideshow trough JavaScript.

Basically the JavaScript gets all of the slides in the slideshow and applies CSS classes to the correct elements to give a nice animated effect, if there is no CSS3 transitions support it will just apply the styles without a transition.

Now, my 'little' problem.
All works as expected, all slides get the correct styles, the code runs without bugs (so far).
But the specified transitions do not work, even though the correct styles where applied.
Also, styles and transitions work when I apply them myself trough the inspector.

Since I couldn't find a logical explanation myself I thought someone here could answer it, pretty please?

I've put together a little example of what the code is right now:
http://g2f.nl/38rvma

Comment: Really not that interesting in opening an untrusted file from an unknown source. How about a nice safe http://jsfiddle.net instead?

Comment: It's just a ZIP file, also I don't believe JSfiddle supports images.
And I believe the users of this site are smart enough to not get a virus from a html file :-)

Comment: Attaching code as a zip either way is not going to get you as far as using jsfiddle (or a similar service) - and no It does not support images, however you could always upload them somewhere else and link to that location... either way - the Internet has sullied users against blindly accepting zip files... even from *trusted* sources..

Comment: If you need image hosting, just [use Stack Overflow's imgur account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 Transitions were introduced to allow animations without JavaScript, so this is counterintuitive. The solution is to [code the animation as a fallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/hh304380), or ask [Stu Nicholls](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/animation.html) for a CSS2 solution.